# ECU Diagnostic Port cut off and Check Engine Light disabled

Tags: engine, honda, electronic-control-module

I bought a used 92 Integra ZXi recently. I had starting issues so I took it to a mechanic. He found that the check engine light is disabled and diagnostic port from the ECU has been cut off. A very bad omen obviously. And yes, I'm stupid.

So now the question I have is - can a generic honda diagnostic port be spliced in, or do I need to find the exact port for my engine (code ZC)?

Comment: Is the diagnostic port physically cut, or is it just not putting out any feed?

Comment: Physically cut out

Comment: How was the check engine light disabled?  Was the wire cut?  If so, you should be able to wire it back in.  You could use a test light on check engine light wire at the ECU.  I would also pop open the ECU to see if the chip has been changed.  You might want to consider getting a factory ECU if it has.

Comment: @rpmerf - not sure yet, trying to find time to take it to an auto electrician and get it reactivated - I just wasn't sure what to do with the diagnostic port

Answer (score 1):

If by "generic" you mean OBD1 or OBD2, the answer seems to be no according to [this website](http://www.4th-gen-civic.com/ecu).

On [another web page](http://hondashapp.blogspot.com/2014/12/obd-compatibility-table.html) the table indicates that it is "OBD0".

Comment: It's OBD1 - the port has been disconnected intentionally

Comment: Yes, even according to the chart you provided, it shows the **92-93 Integra XSi B16A** to be **OBD1**. You must have gandered at the wrong line.

Comment: Well the only ZXi in that table shows OBD0. @gAMBOOKa if you're certain it's OBD1 then that should be standard

Comment: Let me check things out in a couple of hours and get back to you. The engine might have been swapped out in this thing. Btw, if it's OBD0 - is there no way to get any diagnostic codes? So that's a manual check-of-all-things then?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to replace the DLC port is to find a vehicle exactly like yours (or even a close relative) and cut one from it. Then splice the "new" DLC port into your wiring, if you can find the point at which it was cut from the car. This would be an OBDI port you'd be looking for. If you do go this route, take as much wiring as you can get a hold of beyond the port itself. It's a lot easier to cut the wires back than it is to add to them.

I looked for a replacement plug and was unable to find one. I would bet you will not find a new replacement for it anywhere.

I would bet that any 3-pin Honda DLC from an OBD car (95 and older) would probably do the trick. Also, it should be located up under the passenger side in the kick panel area. I'm sure your mechanic knows this, though.

Comment: Let me get some pictures out to forums and find out what engine I've got on this thing - it's supposed to be a ZC acc. to documentation. But I live in a country where documentation is not taken very seriously.